# Edit variables in my main form, from my sub forms

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

This is my first time posting, so please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong!

I've made a WPF form, which is a small RPG text based game. 
I have a button that opens a new form, which is supposed to be a shop. 
I use `var ShopWindow = new Shop(); ShopWindow.ShowDialog();` to open the sub form.

My question is, how do I edit my variables on the main form? 
Let's say I buy something for 10 units, then I want to withdraw 10 units from the main form, and add an item.

I hope I've given enough information, please tell me if you need anything!

Comment: You might be able to pass a callback to the child window. Look into the Action delegate.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get the most out of this website, please take a few moments when you can to read through the useful tips in the StackOverflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

There is so many ways to do that, but the one easy could be lets say:

If you have an input textBox1 on the Shop form, you must change the Modifiers property (at the properties toolbox) from Private to Public, so you will have access to it from your main form and you will be able to do some like this:

```
    var ShopWindow = new Shop(); 
    ShopWindow.ShowDialog();
    var s = ShopWindow.textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: This is a nice way and very simple, but unfortunately impossible to do if the application requires a .Show() and not a .ShowDialog(). The .ShowDialog() will freeze the Thread of mainwindow until the Shop window closes.

Comment: Sure! I just tried to follow the written code sample. In that case, to keep the easy way, could be to create a reference to main form on the child Shop some like: public MainWindow MainWindow { get; set; } and then define:
    var ShopWindow = new Shop(); 
    ShopWindow.ShowDialog();
    ShopWindow.MainWindow = this;


So this will invert the things, by setting to Public the elements wich neededs to be accessibles in the child.

Comment: Yes, this is also a good trick. Another trick is to create a public static MainWindow mw { get; set; } on the App.xaml.cs, and then setting this reference in the constructor of the main window: App.mw = this;   So, the mainwindow can be now accessed from any place. So many ways...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by several ways, but I recommend you to create a custom Action event, in the Shop form.

Let's suppose that you have created a class that represents an item. Put this code in the Shop form:

```
public event Action<Item, int> ItemBought = delegate { };
```

So, now when the user buy an item, you need to call this:

```
ItemBought(item, 30);
```

Where "item" is the item that the player have bought, and 30 is the amount of units that it costs.

Now, in the main window, you need to open the Shop window with this code:

```
Shop s = new Shop();
s.ItemBought += Item_Bought;
s.Show();
```

And add this method that the Shop form will raise in the main window when the player buy an item:

```
internal void Item_Bought(Item item, int cost)
{
     // Update the main window here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to do this is to have a class that represents the user's items, lets call it `Inventory`. In this class, you can put all of the relevant properties, such as `decimal money`, `ObservableCollection<Item> Items`, etc. Then you simply pass an instance of it from the main `Window` to the child `Window` through the constructor:

```
var ShopWindow = new Shop(inventory);
ShopWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Because `inventory` is an object, you're passing a reference to the `Inventory` object from the main `Window`, so any changes you make to it in the child `Window` will be reflected in the main `Window` object too.